# Constructing an IndexColourModel

Tags: java, png, java-2d, color-palette

I was wondering about constructing an [IndexColourModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/IndexColorModel.html). I don't understand the 'bits' parameter argument. Is this what is used to index into a colour map, i.e. the number of least-significant-bits to use from the pixel to index into the map? The docs simply state

```
bits - the number of bits each pixel occupies
```

I'm not satisfied with this and was wondering if someone could elucidate what exactly this parameter is and how it is used. Must this be correlated with the other 'size' parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bits parameter is the [color depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth).

From the [IndexColourModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/IndexColorModel.html) javadoc at the top of the class:

> The values used to index into the colormap are taken from the least
>   significant n bits of pixel representations where n is based on the
>   pixel size specified in the constructor. For pixel sizes smaller than
>   8 bits, n is rounded up to a power of two (3 becomes 4 and 5,6,7
>   become 8). For pixel sizes between 8 and 16 bits, n is equal to the
>   pixel size. Pixel sizes larger than 16 bits are not supported by this
>   class. Higher order bits beyond n are ignored in pixel
>   representations. Index values greater than or equal to the map size,
>   but less than 2n, are undefined and return 0 for all color and alpha
>   components.

Comment: Hi. I read that in the api alright but I thought that the size parameter did this? Also, would I get a better quality image if I used a higher colour depth?

Comment: The size parameter sets the size of the color map.  Aka, how many colors in the color map.  Yes, you'll get better image quality from higher color depths.  Take a look at the [color depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth) Wikipedia entry.  Down the right side it shows examples of the same image with different color depths.